# Prevent a Rails model from saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a scenario where I have a model that I want to populate and validate against, but don't necessarily want to write down to the database when it's parent object is.

For instance, let's say I have an account and a credit card model, the credit card is built against the account, and validated when the account is, but also saved when Account.save! is called.

How can I prevent this model from saving down (because I might not want CC data in my database)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you write your own save! method to replace its base class?

Comment: Tried this, but this returns:

wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

Comment: Did you try adding the same number of arguments as the original method?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [#readonly!](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M001877) method:

Answer (score 1):

Why were you storing the credit card number in the DB at all?

Just add

```
attr_accessor :cc_number
```

Then you won't even need a column in your DB for the credit card.

Comment: "Why were you storing the credit card number in the DB at all?" I think he found a bug and is trying to solve it :P